# How do I save a collection to a user defined data type with an auto increment column?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Assume I have to save a `datatable` with five columns to a **user defined table type** variable with 6 columns. the first column is an auto increment **starts from 1 incremented by 1**

Here is its structure:

```
create type dbo.SelectedCourses
as table
(
    CntrNo int not null IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    CRSID int,
    YearNo int,
    IsCompulsory varchar(20),
    EntDT datetime,
    EmpID int
);
go
```

In the `stored procedure` it is declared as:

```
create proc USPSvUpdtACDProgramFromTypes

-- has global variables above

@pSelCRSInfo as dbo.SelectedCourses READONLY

-- has global variables here
as
begin 
  -- code here
end
```

My problem is how do I construct a `datatable` in the client with 5 columns and add that to a UDTT variable of six columns (first being an `auto increment`). If I assign it without considering the column counts the first column of the `datatable` will be mapped to the auto increment column and SQL will throw an error.

thanks

Comment: in first place why are you constructing a datatable in the client with 5 columns and not using your UDT?

Comment: I haven't I just use the @pSelCRSInfo in the SQLParameter in the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SqlMetaData`

Here is a complete example for UDTT:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[test_table] AS TABLE(
    ID int identity (1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Using the `SqlMetaData`

```
var sqlMetaData = new[] 
{
  new SqlMetaData("ID", SqlDbType.Int, true, false, SortOrder.Unspecified, -1),
  new SqlMetaData("Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
};

var sqlRecords = new HashSet<SqlDataRecord>();
var sqlRec = new SqlDataRecord(sqlMetaData);

sqlRec.SetString(1, "Nyan");
sqlRecords.Add(sqlRec);

var conn = new SqlConnection("connstring");
try
{
    conn.Open();           

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("tests", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var param = new SqlParameter("@tbl", SqlDbType.Structured) { Value = sqlRecords };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error in tests.");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
}
```